# Eclipse maven generate child structure from imported SVN project

Tags: eclipse, maven

I imported a SVN maven project (ik-parent) (Maven Parent) 
This maven project has some maven modules (k-child1 and ik-child2), but the source code in svn is outside parent. At the same level. I don't know why the person did this.

This is the svn structure:

trunk
   | -- ik-parent
               |--pom.xml
   | -- ik-child1
               |--src/..
                 |--pom.xml
    | -- ik-child2
               |-- src/...

               |pom.xml

I did a ckeck-out of trunk. Now in eclipse, I've the same svn structure. I tried to do a maven compile etc.. but it fails 
This is the error: "Child module E:\projects\ik-project\ik-parent\ik-child1 of E:\projects\ik-project\ik-parent\pom.xml does not exist.

How can I generate the module structure inside the parent? For example:

| -- ik-child1
               |--src/..
                 |--pom.xml
    | -- ik-child2
               |-- src/...

               |pom.xml

| -- ik-parent
               |--pom.xml
               | -- ik-child1
                       |--src/..
                         |--pom.xml
               | -- ik-child2
                       |-- src/...

                       |pom.xml

Comment: I solved it. First I did ik-parent checkout (only ik-parent project). After this, I checked out ik-child1 and ik-child2 and in the destination I unchecked default and I put the ik-parent path.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. First I did ik-parent checkout (only ik-parent project). After this, I checked out ik-child1 and ik-child2 and in the destination I unchecked default and I put the ik-parent path.

Answer (score 0):

`E:\projects\ik-project\ik-parent\ik-child1` looks like the `pom.xml` of `ik-parent` contains the children as `ik-child1` instead of as `../ik-child1`.

Look for the `<modules>` element in the POM. It contains relative paths to the child modules (and not the artifact IDs of the children). If you fix the relative paths, then checking out `trunk` should work.